# Taking a Github Project in a Different Direction

Tags: git, github

Good evening,

I found a github project that has a significant codebase that gets me 75% of the way to what I would like to do.  It is relatively new (i.e. it will probably see frequent updates) and I would like to take it in my own direction.

I am fairly new to git.... is there any easy way to keep myself up to date with the github master, while at the same time straying away in my own direction?

i.e. If I keep my local master in sync with the github repo (git pull --ff-only upstream master), and work on my own branch, is there an easy command where I can easily apply all of my commits to an updated master branch, keeping the two separate?

(I'm sure this is a relatively simple operation for someone knowledgable in git!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use git rebase, which will move all the commits on your branch so they are based off an updated master branch.

After updating master from upstream as in the question, you do

git rebase master my-branch

Now it is as if my-branch was made from the most up-to-date master commit.

Comment: Hi Antlersoft - how does rebasing differ from the merging suggested by @Amber?  I can provide my email address if it is easier to explain there.  Cheers!

Comment: When you merge, the changes from the other branch appear as a single commit in the history of your branch (not in the case of fast-forward merges, but you won't be able to do that in general).  So the two development histories become commingled, which you seem to be trying to avoid.  When you rebase, the changes on your branch are uprooted from your previous branch point and put at the end of the branch that you are tracking-- all the commits on your branch remain in sequence, without being commingled with commits from the other branch.  This seems to be what you were asking for.

Comment: Yeah I think so!  Thanks.  Applying my set of changes from an update branch appears to be the cleanest way to keep my code separate and allow the main codebase to continue to update.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `master` branch which is updated in accordance with the remote master, and then a local `self` branch that is your own work, you can make a third `combined` branch that integrates both via the following:

```
git checkout master -b combined
git merge self
```

This will create the branch `combined` based off of your `master` branch, and then merge in your `self` branch, creating a result that has both branches' changes.

Alternatively, you could just merge `master` into your `self` branch repeatedly, if you want all of the upstream changes in your own working branch.